# Mockito Unable to mock code within FlatMap RxJava

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, project-reactor

I have a code block with a flatMap which I'm trying to test, but it seems Mockito does not go inside the flatMap.

Here is my actual code class Code.java

```
private final ObjectResolver objectResolver;

public Mono<String> function toTest(Object obj) {
    return Mono.just(obj)
        .flatMap(obj -> objectResolver.resolve(obj.getField())
             .map(resolved -> StringUtils.join(resolved.getField(), obj.getAnotherField())))
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to test it out:

```
@InjectMocks
private Code code

@Mock
private ObjectResolver objectResolver

@Test
void testToTest() {
    when(objectResolver.resolve(any()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ResolvedObject()));
    StepVerifier.create(code.toTest(new Object()))
        .expectNext("resultString")
        .verifyComplete();
}
```

Mockito doesn't seem to go within the flatMap when I try to debug. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the constructor(s) for the `Code` class?  InjectMocks is a bit fussy about whether to choose a constructor, or try to inject the fields directly.  If it can't find a suitable constructor, it might go for field injection, and fall over because of the `final`.

Comment: have you seen this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883605/how-to-test-function-inside-rxjava-flatmap

Comment: Can you confirm which line is throwing the Exception?   On some tests, it’s failing on the `when` before it ever involves the code under test - in which case the solution is to simply use `doReturn(Mono.just(new ResolvedObject())).when(objectResolver).resolve(any())`.   Note the different syntax here, that the `when` contains only the object, not the call to `resolve`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I'm using Lombok's RequiredArgsConstructor

Comment: @GvSharma, yes I tried that too, unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: @racraman, I'm not getting an exception, but an unnecessary stubbing from Mockito and no coverage on the code inside the flatmap.

Comment: My advice would be to try it without the Lombok annotation.  Mockito uses its own reflection, and I don't know whether it will find the methods generated by Lombok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe the mono to release the item.

```html
@Test
void testToTest() {
    when(objectResolver.resolve(any()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ResolvedObject()));
    StepVerifier.create(code.toTest(new Object()))
        .expectNext("resultString")
        .verifyComplete();
        
        Mono<String> returnedMono = code.toTest(new Object());
        returnedMono.subscribe();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).